# Vim: substitution in a range that is less than a line

Tags: vim, replace, substitution

Let's say I have the following line of code:

```
something:somethingElse:anotherThing:woahYetAnotherThing
```

And I want to replace each `:` with a `;` *except the first one*, such that the line looks like this:

```
something:somethingElse;anotherThing;woahYetAnotherThing
```

Is there a way to do this with the `:[range]s/[search]/[replace]/[options]` command without using the `c` option to confirm each replace operation?

As far as I can tell, the smallest range that `s` acts on is a single line. If this is true, then what is the fastest way to do the above task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm fairly new to vim myself; I think you're right about range being lines-only (not 100% certain), but for this specific example you might try replacing all of the instances with a global flag, and then putting back the first one by omitting the global -- something like `:s/:/;/g|s/;/:/`.

Note: if the line contains a `;` before the first `:` then this will not work.

Comment: Just to be completely archaic: `s/:/;/g|s/~/:/`. The `~` search pattern matches the last substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you could use a single keystroke to do what you want (by mapping capital *Q*):

`map Q :s/:/;/g\|:s/;/:<Enter>j`

Every time you press <kbd>Q</kbd> the current line will be modified and the cursor will move to the next line.

In other words, you could just keep hitting <kbd>Q</kbd> multiple times to edit each successive line.

Explanation:

This will operate globally on the current line:

`:s/:/;/g`

This will switch the first semi-colon back to a colon:

`:s/;/:`

The answer by @AlliedEnvy combines these into one statement.

My map command assigns @AlliedEnvy's answer to the capital Q character.

---

Another approach (what I would probably do if I only had to do this once):

<kbd>f</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>;</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>;</kbd><kbd>;</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>

Then you can repeatedly press <kbd>;</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> until you reach the end of the line.

(Your choice to replace a semi-colon makes this somewhat comfusing)

Explanation:

- <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> - go to the first colon
- <kbd>;</kbd> - go to the next colon (repeat in-line search)
- <kbd>r</kbd><kbd>;</kbd> - replace the current character with a semi-colon
- <kbd>;</kbd> - repeat the last in-line search (again)
- <kbd>.</kbd> - repeat the last command (replace current character with a semi-colon)

Long story short:

- <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> - moves to the next occurrence of `x` on the current line
- <kbd>;</kbd> repeats the last inline search

Answer (score 2):

Here you go...

```
:%s/\(:.*\):/\1;/|&|&|&|&
```

This is a simple regex substitute that takes care of one single *not-the-first* `:`.

The `&` command repeats the last substitute.

The `|` syntax separates multiple commands on one line. So, each substitute is repeated as many times as there are `|&` things.

Answer (score 2):

While the other answers work well for this particular case, here's a more general solution:

Create a visual selection starting from the second element to the end of the line. Then, limit the substitution to the visual area by including `\%V`:

```
:'<,'>s/\%V:/;/g
```

Alternatively, you can use the [vis.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1195)

```
:'<,'>B s/:/;/g
```